# filter only week days and filter only weekend in hive

Tags: mysql, date, hadoop, hive

I have a column named '*timestamp*' and I want to filter only weekdays data in one query and weekend data in another query in **Hive**

time_stamp

```
2018-03-12 15:30:00.0 --Monday
2018-03-13 15:30:00.0 --Tuesday
2018-03-14 15:30:00.0 --Wednesday
2018-03-15 15:30:00.0 --Thursday
2018-03-16 15:30:00.0 --Friday
2018-03-17 15:30:00.0 --Saturday
2018-03-18 15:30:00.0 --Sunday
2018-03-19 15:30:00.0 --Monday
```

The result I'm looking for is

```
2018-03-12 15:30:00.0 --Monday
2018-03-13 15:30:00.0 --Tuesday
2018-03-14 15:30:00.0 --Wednesday
2018-03-15 15:30:00.0 --Thursday
2018-03-16 15:30:00.0 --Friday
2018-03-19 15:30:00.0 --Monday
```

This is not my Strong point.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can play with `from_unixtime` and `unix_timestamp`

This will return day of week:

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2018-03-12 15:30:00.0'), 'E')
```

and your full query will look like this:

```
select * from mytable where from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(time_stamp), 'E') in ('Mon', 'Tue', ...) ;
```

Here is full description of date functions in hive: [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions)

Answer (score 0):

In hive you can get the name of days by using combination of `unix_timestamp`, and `from_unixtime` UDFs.

so first you have to get name of days

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col), 'EEE') as days
```

If you want full name of days you can used `EEEE`

then you can filter weekends usging

```
where days != "Sat" or days != "Sun"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
desc datetoday;
OK
date1                   timestamp

select * from datetoday;
OK
2018-03-12 15:30:00
2018-03-13 15:30:00
2018-03-14 15:30:00
2018-03-15 15:30:00
2018-03-16 15:30:00
2018-03-17 15:30:00
2018-03-18 15:30:00
2018-03-19 15:30:00
Time taken: 0.101 seconds, Fetched: 8 row(s)
hive> select date1,from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(date1,'yyyy-mm-dd'),'E') from datetoday;
OK
2018-03-12 15:30:00 Mon
2018-03-13 15:30:00 Tue
2018-03-14 15:30:00 Wed
2018-03-15 15:30:00 Thu
2018-03-16 15:30:00 Fri
2018-03-17 15:30:00 Sat
2018-03-18 15:30:00 Sun
2018-03-19 15:30:00 Mon
Time taken: 0.095 seconds, Fetched: 8 row(s)
```